# Number of terms in multivariate polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

We know that the number of terms in a univariate polynomial of degree n is n+1.
But what about if there are multiple variables:
for eg: for variables $x,y$ polynomial of degree 2 will have:

$1+x+y+xy+x^2+y^2$

(By degree, here i mean the combined power of $x$ and $y$)

To find out the number of temrs in a polynomial with $r$ variables of degree $n$.

I found out the number of terms of each power (combined power) up-to $n$ and summed them.

The number of terms of power $k$ will be equivalent to the number of non-negative integral solutions of :

$p_1 + p_2 + ... p_r = k$

which is equal to $ k+r-1 \choose r-1$.

So i figured the number of terms in the polynomial will be:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {k+r-1 \choose r-1}$

Is there a way to simplify the above sum into a single term (like $\sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r} = 2^n$)?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this was also answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225953/number-of-polynomial-terms-for-certain-degree-and-certain-number-of-variables):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n h_k(1,...,1)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{r+k-1}{k}=\binom{r+n}{n}.$$